# Invalid arguments error in code for Python server

Tags: python

I am trying to write a server mainly from class examples as have no idea what is going on.  I am having a problem  with the line -

```
(input,output,err)=select.select(socks,[],[])
```

I get the error 'invalid arguments' I have no idea how to fix this.  I have written it out the same as shown in class.  Can someone help me with this? thank you.

```
  #Server
    import select
    import socket
    import math
    import random



    def within(guess,goal,n):
        absValue = abs(guess - goal)
        if absValue <= n:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    scoreCount = 0
    guess = 0

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1",9000))
    s.listen(5)

    socks = []

    while True:
        (input,output,err)=select.select(socks,[],[])

        for i in input:
            if (i == s):
                (c,a) = s.accept()
                socks.append(c)
                print ("Received connection from", a)
                hello = c.recv(1024).decode()
                print(hello)
                c.send('Greetings\r\n'.encode())

                goal = random.randrange(1,21)

                while guess!= goal:
                    guess =c.recv(1024).decode()
                    guess = int(guess[7:len(guess)-2])

                    if guess == goal:
                        c.send('correct\r\n'.encode())
                    elif within(guess, goal, 2) == True:
                        c.send('close\r\n'.encode())
                    else:
                        c.send('far\r\n'.encode())
            c.close()
```

Comment: [Have you tried reading the documentation?](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html)

Comment: `Empty sequences are allowed, but acceptance of three empty sequences is platform-dependent. (It is known to work on Unix but not on Windows.)`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what that means.

Comment: I'm afraid that document may as well be written in Japanese.  I don't understand a word of it